# What is meaning of the *fractional* (not integer) number $x$ in $Ga_xIn_{1-x}As$ for semiconductor composite?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

So far, for *molecule*, I had learned the indice parameter $x$ as a *integer* number.

But what is meaning of the *fractional* (not integer) number $x$ in $Ga_xIn_{1-x}As$ for semiconductor composite ?

Is is a fraction, but for what ? For which ensemble ?

Should $Ga_xIn_{1-x}As$ be interpreted as a *molecule* or not at all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Indium gallium arsenide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indium_gallium_arsenide) is an [alloy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alloy) of indium arsenide and gallium arsenide. The notation $\mathrm{Ga}_x\mathrm{In}_{1-x}\mathrm{As}$ denotes the alloy obtained from alloying the two metals in a ratio $x:1-x$, it is not a formula for a molecule. As an (alloyed) metal, the compound in solid form has an crystal lattice structure, and does not present as discrete molecules of any kind.